# Going back to main view using the navigation bar back button

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xcode6, uinavigationbar

My app has a main view with a few buttons lined up vertically. Each button is linked to a different view controller. Now, when the user taps on the first button, the first view controller is opened. Within the first view controller, there is a button which takes you directly to the second view controller. When I get to the second view controller, and press the back button, I am taken back to the first view controller. Then I have to press the back button one more time to be taken to the main view controller. What can I do to make the app take me directly to the main view controller from the second view controller, and not through the first view controller? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to go back to RootViewController from presentView controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755916/how-to-go-back-to-rootviewcontroller-from-presentview-controller)

Answer (score 0):

You could bypass the segue_unwind to go back to the main view controller. Just call the performSegueWithIdentifier in the IBAction of the button

## Swift

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueIdentifierName", sender: self)
```

## Objective C

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifierName" sender:self];
```

Here is a similar article as well
[What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)

Comment: I understood everything the answers on the question in the link said except one thing. One step was to link the button to the exit. But, I don't have a button. It is the back button on the navigation bar itself. What can I do then?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of answers in SO about this BUT:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

OR

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers firstObject];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:YES];
```

Should work just fine.

Next time, **TRY** to find answers first:
[How do I get the RootViewController from a pushed controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792858/how-do-i-get-the-rootviewcontroller-from-a-pushed-controller)

Comment: How should I link this to the UINavigationBar back button?

Comment: @KrishWadhwana you cannot do this. Instead, remove the 1st view controller from the stack, when you push the 2nd.

Comment: `NSMutableArray *vc = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] mutableCopy];
[vc removeObjectAtIndex:1];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:vc];`

Answer (score 0):

You can override the back button action to call popToViewController() on the navigationController with the view controller you would like to return to.

Comment: How should I override the UINavigationBar back button action?

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 3.01

```
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueIdentifierName", sender: self)
```