# If no internet connection go to rootviewcontroller in swift

Tags: swift, rootviewcontroller

I am checking if there is or not internet connection before calling any service method. If there's no internet, I am showing an alert and if I click ok button I want to go to root view controller.

Here's my code:

```
if TLReachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true{
    // do here 
} 
else {
    let navigationController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let changeViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TLLoginViewController") as! TLLoginViewController
    navigationController.presentViewController(changeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: What's your question exactly, are you getting a crash? What is the result of your code example?

Comment: if no internet connect , i want to go root view controller

Comment: its not going to root view controller , the code is in NSobject class

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755916/how-to-go-back-to-rootviewcontroller-from-presentview-controller

Comment: I have tried that also no use by using that

Comment: Your code sample doesn't seem connected to your question.  Where are you testing your connection?  How are you trying to return to the root?

Comment: @Ravi: please edit your code example above with exactly what you are doing, don't use short snippets.

Comment: above code is written in else

Answer (score 0):

```
let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "ALERT", message: "NO INTERNET", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { action -> Void in
    let rootViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RootViewController") as! RootViewController
    navigationController.presentViewController(changeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your code on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
  let navigationController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController 
  navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
})
```